# How to write a shell script to find out which node is acting as a master in CQ5 cluster environment

Tags: linux, shell, aem, master-slave

I have my Adobe CQ5 servers in Linux environment (Redhat). I have to write a shell script to find out which node is acting as a Master presently in CQ5 Cluster environment. 
My CQ5 clustering environment includes 1 author acting as Master node and another as Slave node.

Please suggest me if it is possible to find out which is the Master node using shell script.

Answer (score 0):

try looking at the [ClusterAware Interface](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/jcrclustersupport/ClusterAware.html)?

especially ClusterAware.bindRepository(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, boolean)

Create a servlet that your shell script can curl...